# Filter out elements of a list based on their interrelationship

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm working an interesting python problem:

Given a list of integer, bacteria, and a positive integer constant, K, if there are two elements i and j meet the criteria that:

```
j < i <= j + K
```

design a function to make i stay and remove j, and return the minimal possible number of the elements in the list.

The function: `micro_world(bacteria, K)`

For instance,

```
bacteria = [101, 53, 42, 102, 101, 55, 54]
K = 1
```

The end result shall be

```
 [42,102,55]
```

and therefore 3 shall be returned.

Similarly

`micro_world([101, 53, 42, 102, 101, 55, 54], 1)` shall give me a result of 3

`micro_world([20, 15, 10, 15, 20, 25], 5)` shall give me a result of  1

I'm thinking of using list comprehension to filter out the elements that do not meet the criterion above, hence getting the elements I want. But I'm not sure how to go on with it since it involves the relationship between each element in the list.

```
result = [ i for i in bacteria if ... ]
```

What shall I use for my if statement?

If this is not a good way, what shall I do instead?

Thanks.

Edit: 
Both answers have provided utterly good instructions for me. But there's just one small thing about the repetitive values in the bacteria list. For instance, if the input

```
bacteria = [3, 3]
```

even though this is just one chunk, the result shall be 2 since 3 !> 3 hence neither shall be removed.

Comment: @timgeb OK, I will try to do it from that angle. But I sort of failed to see how my question is the duplicate of the question that it's marked. I specifically created a clone to avoid that situation. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many copies you create if you still iterate over the list you're removing values from.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks. I will try to filter it using list comprehension. Any tip on how it shall look like? I'm trying to figure out how to fit both i and j in the list comprehension if statements.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Is my question valid now? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to solve this with a list comprehension. The easy fix is to create another copy of the `bacteria` list and iterate over that. But there are (I think) better solutions like sorting the list and then only iterating over it once, discarding the undesired elements.

Comment: Please add some sample input and output to the question. It's near-impossible to understand as it is now.

Comment: @Aran-Fey my bad, doing it now.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks. So using `list.append()`? But what shall the code be? I feel like I can't simply reverse the condition in this case since `j` may not meet criteria of the next `i` as the iteration goes on. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aran-Fey could you elaborate a little please? Are you talking about `append` or `remove` approach? I tried the sorting method, but it actually gave me worse results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're essentially trying to group your list of numbers into chunks where each number is less than `k` apart from another number in that chunk. Because I'm bad at explaining things, let's look at an example:

```
bacteria = [101, 53, 42, 102, 101, 55, 54]
K = 1
```

First, we want to sort that list so that numbers are arranged by their magnitude:

```
[102, 101, 101, 55, 54, 53, 42]
```

Now we iterate over the list and create a new chunk of numbers every time the bigger bacterium can't swallow the smaller one:

```
[[102, 101, 101], [55, 54, 53], [42]]
```

Finally we count the number of chunks, and thus obtain the desired result: 3.

Code:

```
def micro_world(bacteria, k):
    # sort the list descendingly
    bacteria = sorted(bacteria, reverse=True)

    # loop over the list but skip all the "swallowed" bacteria
    i = 0
    result = 0
    while i < len(bacteria):
        bacterium_size = bacteria[i]

        # while the difference between the numbers is <= k, the smaller
        # bacterium is swallowed
        bigger_bacterium_exists = False
        while i+1 < len(bacteria):
            difference = bacterium_size - bacteria[i+1]

            # if the difference is too big, it can't be swallowed
            if difference > k:
                break

            # if there are two bacteria of the same size, they can't swallow
            # each other. But if a bigger bacterium exists, it can swallow
            # them both
            if difference == 0 and not bigger_bacterium_exists:
                break

            # all conditions are met, the bacterium is swallowed
            bacterium_size = bacteria[i+1]
            i += 1
            bigger_bacterium_exists = True

        # at this point, the bacterium has swallowed everything it can.
        # Increment the result counter and move on to the next bacterium.
        result += 1
        i += 1

    return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think of this approach and your answer truly provided me with a new perspective. But this method doesn't seem to deal very well with the repeat values. For instance, if `bacteria = [5, 5]` then `i !> j' therefore there shall be two chunks as result but your code will yield 1. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks again.

Comment: @BowenLiu You're saying duplicate numbers should create extra chunks? But then wouldn't the output of `micro_world([20, 15, 10, 15, 20, 25], 5)` be 3, because of the duplicated 15 and 20? I don't quite understand the logic here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm super bad at explaining things really. That case is fine since the duplicate 15 will be eliminated as 15 < 20 <= 15 + K, which is 20. But if it's just `[5, 5]` then it won't work since `5 < 5 <= 5 +K` is invalid. I'm working on this [codeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/micro-world), maybe its description  will help you understand. My bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just got a chance to try it. Just to make sure: `break` will take the stop the current iteration and go back to the upper level (I'm sure I'm not using the correct terminology here, I mean like back to the previous indentation) right? And how did you decide that while loop is better than for loop in this case? Thanks again

Comment: @BowenLiu That's correct, yes. I'm using `while` loops because both loops share the same index `i`. That's harder to do with two `for` loops.

Comment: Good point. Understood now. Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def micro_world(bacteria, K):
    # convert bacteria list to a numpy array:
    bacteria = np.asarray(bacteria)

    # sort array and remember the indices used for sorting:
    sarg = np.argsort(bacteria)
    sortedbac = bacteria[sarg]

    # compute differences between adjacent elements:
    diff = np.ediff1d(sortedbac, K + 1)

    # throw away elements that are too close to neighbors
    # (find indices of the elements to keep):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(diff > K)

    # create a new list that meets selection criteria:
    return bacteria[np.sort(sarg[idx])]
```

---

Here is a "pure" Python implementation:

```
def micro_world(bacteria, K):
    # sort array and remember the indices used for sorting:
    sarg = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(bacteria), key=lambda x: x[1])]
    sortedbac = [bacteria[i] for i in sarg]

    # compute differences between adjacent elements:
    diff = [j - i for i, j in zip(sortedbac[:-1], sortedbac[1:])] + [K + 1]

    # throw away elements that are too close to neighbors
    # (find indices of the elements to keep):
    idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(diff) if v > K]

    # create a new list that meets selection criteria:
    return [bacteria[i] for i in sorted([sarg[i] for i in idx])]
```

---

If you are interested only in the *number* of elements and not in the elements themselves, then you can modify i.e. the second version as follows:

```
def micro_world(bacteria, K):
    sortedbac = sorted(bacteria)
    diff = [j - i for i, j in zip(sortedbac[:-1], sortedbac[1:])] + [K + 1]
    return sum(1 for v in diff if v > K)
```

The `numpy` version would then become:

```
def micro_world(bacteria, K):
    return np.sum(np.ediff1d(np.sort(bacteria), K + 1) > K)
```